# Display Color swatch option in product listing page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, color-swatches, product-listing

I want to display color images on product listing page https://prnt.sc/sush2z.
I have made color attribute and selected swatch option. Assigned color images too. https://nimb.ws/Sw9mEN

Did Visible on product listing as yes https://nimb.ws/ux3R5y

Still it does not show on product listing page.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

.check this file

`module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`

around line number 72

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()) :?>
  <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code is responsible to show the swatches in frontend.

You can add it in your theme in the below file

```
app/design/frontend/{Themepackage}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

Hope it solves your issue.